# Alignment of images and texts in Java on Windows and Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, javafx, alignment

I'm having some trouble loading images and texts into my Java application. I'm using JavaFX and Scene Builder to help me design everything. The program works perfectly, except that when I execute it in Windows, the alignment of the image and text change, like they are in different positions when compared to Linux. The program  was all constructed in Linux, but i need it to run on Windows too. Is there any way to fix that ?
Thanks.

Comment: We can't help you , unless you show us some code or at least link us to some images of what exactly is happening.

Comment: Have you tried a different JavaFX theme ? (Caspian - Modena - Metro etc...)